# How can I add context (or distinguish between contexts) to translations with t()?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have made a custom address handler for the Addressfield module which uses the word "state" (for the geographic state/province).  However, I'm also using the Revisioning module, which uses the word "State" to describe the state of a piece of content.

Unfortunately, to translate this into Japanese, I need two different words for "State"; how can I get two different strings to appear on the translate interface screen?

(I know I could just re-write "State" in revisioning to something like "Revisioning state" but I'd like to know if there's a way to handle this without altering the strings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a context to [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7), see the third parameter, $options. However, you can only do this in the source code, which means that it is often not helpful. Might be possible in your case, because it's your own code.