# Can't figure out how to set a context with t()

Tags: i18n-l10n

This is a follow-up to [this question on setting contexts using t()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32075/how-can-i-add-context-or-distinguish-between-contexts-to-translations-with-t).

I am attempting to set a context using [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7).

I am trying to set the *context* for the translation of **State** to *geo*.  My code looks like this:

```
$format['locality_block']['administrative_area'] = array(
  '#title' => t('State', array('context' => 'geo')),
  '#size' => 10,
);
```

This doesn't give any errors but it also doesn't create the translation unit with the context, either.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong?  (It's probably something obvious; I'm not good with PHP.)

Comment: The second argument of the t function ar replacements and not options...
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

Comment: @lenni You should put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of the [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/) function are the replacements and not options.

Comment: For those like me who struggle with PHP, here is the code I used that worked; `'#title' => t('State', array(), array('context' => 'geo')),`